# WorkflowApplication output

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

In order to get output from Workflowinvoker we have to use

```
          var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new Activity1() { str = night  });
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(output["res"]);
```

but what do we have to use for the WorkflowApplication command? I tried the same as Workflowinvoker but it doesnt works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.completed.aspx) callback.  The WorkflowApplication executes the workflow asynchronously, whereas the WorkflowInvoker blocks until it completes.

```
var flag = new ManualResetEvent(); 
var app = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
Dictionary<string,object> results = null;
app.Completed = x =>
{
    results = x.Outputs;
    flag.Set();
};
app.Run();
// run the application, wait for it to complete
flag.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
// Completed has executed at this point
```

Comment: hm i got the following error on x.Outputs -  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: i tried it with IDictionary and Dictionary but it doesnt work

Comment: when i put IDictionary and i run it i get a null reference exception on  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(output["res"]);

Comment: @pikk: You can't cast an IDictionary to a Dictionary.  Change the variable type.  As to why 'output' is null, I can't tell you.  Seems like you have lots to learn here.

Comment: this is my code. IDictionary<string, object> output = null;
            app.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs o)
            {
               
                    output= o.Outputs;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(output["res"]); But when i check the output contents on the debugger it has the correct values. how is it possible to get an exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @pikk: okay, this is getting way out of scope.  You need to check the current HttpContext and the Response property.

Comment: what exactly do you mean to "check"?

Comment: @pikk: `if(HttpContext.Current != null) //etc`.  Seems like you're *way* over your head here.